# mailchimp extension in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, mailchimp, firebase-extensions

I would like the mailchimp extension in firebase to sent the field displayName to mailchimp as firstName (or as a custom field, I dont mind either way.
I used https://extensions.dev/extensions/mailchimp/mailchimp-firebase-sync and put in
Firebase Member Tags Config the following:

json { "memberTags": ["displayName"], "firstName": "displayName" }

Which did not work. How do I fix this?